# Sales team keep on setting aggressive deadlines

Tags: scrum, project-team, sales

So I had a quick meeting today, my Boss who is leading the sales team has given me one sprint to deliver a shopping list of work for a end client.

I have told him that a week is not enough time to deliver that amount of work and properly test everything. Only in the best case scenario, if everything works fantastically well, it will be delivered.

I am currently facing the following issues:

- My boss doesn't seem to care and will just set the aggressive deadlines anyway because it's an opportunity to get business in.
- My boss is not respecting the fact that my team are contractually obliged to work 40 hours a week (UK), he just wants this level of work delivered in a sprint even if it means a lot of overtime.

I have warned him about:

- Tech debt resulting from very aggressive deadlines and being able to create a contingency in my project management.
- I have repeatedly told him that we can't let clients dictate our sprint cycles this way, but his argument is that if we are not aggressive enough with timeframes we will lose business.

How can I handle this situation.

Comment: You need to learn to say "no," and mean it.

Comment: His argument that you'll lose business without these "aggressive" timelines is utter bs. Consistently failing to deliver on time will do far more harm to the business in the long run. I wish I had better advice than "find a new job"...

Comment: What is your role on this team?

Comment: Project manager, where the problem is happening is that the sales team are setting my deadlines for me without getting me involved. I can understand why, because they are under pressure to get sales so are promising unrealistic deadlines to drive sales.

Comment: Scrum doesn't have a "Project Manager" role. Are you the Scrum Master, the Product Owner, or something else? I have two answers right now for a traditional Scrum team with what the Scrum Master and what the Product Owner should be doing.

Comment: It sounds like you aren't doing Scrum and your manager isn't bought into it at all. This isn't how commitments are made and there is no project manager role. I assume you're looking for an answer in the context of your traditional metholdogy rather than the scrum answer?

Comment: Someone has to decide, either you will use Scrum and follow its rules or you can stop playing on one. If the management does not want to accept that team defines work to be done in an iteration they should just say: We do not want Scrum. Also if the Scrum Master in not strong enough (not a criticism, but sometime s/he does not have enough support in the organization) the project should ask for some outside consulting which organization would value enough.

Comment: @NathanCooper I am trying very hard to maintain scrum practices, facing some resistance.  I know that it is working extremely well (when my sprint cycles are not disrupted) because like this week we had a sprint, and my team helped me deliver high quality work ahead of schedule.

Comment: I am also the scrum master here.

Answer (score 8):

Reflect the pain back.

As things stand, your boss is not feeling the pain the team is feeling in delivering against artificial and aggressive deadlines. Your challenge is to make sure they see the consequences of their actions.

Produce a sprint report that details what has or has not been tested. Make it clear that by accepting a release under these conditions your boss is also accepting the responsibility for any bugs that arise from untested code.

For example:

> "We have managed to test the new features delivered in this sprint, but we have not had time to do any regression testing nor have we we tested on other browsers or devices. The product may well have bugs that we have not discovered."

Do the same kind of thing with code quality. Every time you rush a delivery you build up technical debt and you reduce the quality of your code. This can be reflected back in terms of the difficulty of doing future enhancements on the code base:

> "In order to achieve the last delivery deadline we had to hard code a number of values rather than using a more effective coding approach. The code base will be harder to work on now and as such we are likely to be slower to deliver any future work."

Finally, emphasise the impact of working long hours on the team:

> "The team has been working evenings and some weekends for several weeks now. Team morale is low and motivation is much reduced. As the team members are tired all the time they are making more mistakes, which is resulting in increasing amounts of re-work."

Comment: Thank you Barnaby, that is really helpful. I have started this process with my boss but it is taking a lot of time for him to get around to the idea that aggressive sales deadlines do not work.

Comment: I have found that a lot of non-technical managers assume that pushing hard with tight deadlines is the best way to get results. They have seen this work with sales and other areas of the business. Most don't realise that software development is a knowledge based industry and that this kind of management approach doesn't usually work.

Comment: Barnaby - that is awesome.  It does not tackle the root cause of simply "not really doing Scrum" but it is the absolute best response.  Great answer.  It will drive the conversation to where it needs to go.

Comment: @ Venture2099 yes exactly. I am tired of reading comments that 'we are not really doing scrum', the problem is not knowing how to do it, but to be able to do it in such a way where everyone is happy.

Comment: I am a non technical manager and got some down votes around challenging the team on the previous question by the OP.  What I have found, @BarnabyGolden, is that SW developers consider themselves and IT projects different than every other type of project and project worker out there.  Yet there is no logical evidence as to why that might be.  IT is not the only knowledge based industry out there.

Comment: @DavidEspina the problem is that it is hard to accurately estimate how long something will take in software development. Implementation, testing, bug fixing can not be estimated accurately using time, whereas in other industries you can do this. For example; if I am asked to serve pop corn I can measure how much time it takes to put into a container accurately and so I can tell a customer it will take 50 seconds. This will always be the same, and there will be no unknowns. This is where I think that velocity which is apart of Scrum is a fantastic concept and software dev is different.

Comment: Comparing popcorn and IT is not helpful.  There are other highly complex non IT knowledge engagements where estimating is very difficult.  A strategy engagement with a ton of research is such an example.  Even transportation is difficult with the variables that can affect a trucker to get someplace on time.  IT really is not that different.  You guys just think it is.

Comment: @ David Espina, how do you run your projects - do you use agile? Yes I agree that transportation can be difficult for similar reasons. Often the problem with IT projects as a former developer and now PM is that it is very hard to do tonnes of research before starting a task. You often really find out for example how to solve a bug once you get stuck into solving it, compound that with the client asking you beforehand 'how long it will take to fix it', and that is where the problem lies. At least with transportation you can use tools to show you weather forecasts, congestion levels etc.

Comment: Everything we do in life is probabilistic, even those tasks like laying carpet.  It sounds like you want to always use a planning value that is way out there on the range to ensure you will achieve the objective every time, like P90 or above.  Anything below that is "aggressive."  If that's true, you're boss is right.  You will lose business.

Comment: @ David Espina I plan based on velocity, I use story points to give an approximate measure the complexity of tasks in a sprint. Every Monday when I start my sprints, I ask the product owner what the goal of that week (i.e. sprint). The team then has to respect it, if the team consistently never meet the sprint goals, then there is a serious problem. With client tasks it is the same, I will factor their work into the sprints, since we have more than 1 client if we keep on taking on work with tight deadlines and short notice the project management is going to break when resources are blocked

Comment: @ David Espina, to add, the idea is to release the product in increments.

Answer (score 2):

This is precisely why I like the Kanban approach to PM.

1. Make a big unordered list of all the "wist list" features people have requested.
2. Rank each feature/story in priority order. Which ones must be done now and will help the business?
3. Once you agree on the priorities, the implementation is in your court. It shouldn't matter if the top story is going to take 6 weeks and the 2nd is going to take 2 hours. Sure, you could deliver it faster, but it's not the most important so don't do it yet.
4. You and your manager need to agree that you're not going to ship a feature that isn't complete. You'll focus as many resources (people, budgets, time, attention, etc.) on the stories in the agreed upon order and they'll be delivered to the customers when they're complete. No sooner and no later.

This is, without dispute, the fastest way to deliver value to the customers in the shortest timeframe. If, in a week, your manager says he needs a different feature delivered first, you say, "Great. Let's sit down and look at the priorities. Do we both agree that B should be done before A?"

If it's better for the business, then drop everything and do B. It's okay to make that decision as long as everyone knows what the costs & ramifications will be.

Comment: Often thought about switching to kanban, but that means ditching burn down charts - there is just something about scrum that I like

Comment: @bobo2000: Even with Scrum you can use the described approach. The major difference is that you will take a set of stories from the product backlog at once (this becomes the sprint backlog) and if you boss wants to change the set of stories in the sprint, the complete set gets dropped and you start planning a new sprint (this is called abnormal sprint termination).

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau defeats the point of Scrum in my opinion if I keep having to recreate the sprint backlog once a change requests comes through. Often individual stories gets changed, not the entire backlog from experience.

Comment: @bobo2000: Abnormal sprint termination should not happen very often. But it is also a very clear message to management that changing the priorities of work being produced right now is costly. That alone should be enough to let them think twice about how important the new request really is.

Comment: @bobo2000 is correct. Your manager isn't feeling the pain or seeing the cost of these late changes. If they request a shift in priorities, you need to show the the backlog and ask where this new feature should be prioritized. The great thing about a stacked rank is that it becomes very clear that when you insert one tiny story, everything else is pushed down. That makes the cost very clear.

Comment: How are you measuring stacked ranking i.e. via the position of the backlog?

Answer (score 0):

A well covered and detailed answer for the situation. Ensure you share few emails and reports supporting the facts about the difficulties and the flaws of tight and unrealistic goals for the team. Adding few of the tools through which each of this could be achieved.

Maintain a well documented and self explanatory **Tracibility Matrix**. This would cover the Scenarios and the Test cases that were executed in a specific Sprint for a release. In a release report mention the features that were not regressed. Make a practice to share a release report.

During your emails about the Code freeze details, mention the Code has not been **self reviewed and Peer reviewed**, due to the deadlines. The testing team is waiting the the implemented feature for their test activities. Thus, opening gates for few obvious issues.

Regarding the team moral and motivation issues. Do monthly **one to one meeting** with the team members. The goal of the meeting should be to set a monthly goal for the team members and identify and resolve any roadblocks for them. In such a scenario, the team members will come with issues that would be a red flag for the management. Share the same and seek solution to their issues.

Once, these discussions would come on the table, the management team and the HR team would look for a solution to the current difficulties the team is facing.

Answer (score -2):

At the risk of more down votes:

This kind of question leads to a ton of feel good answers for labor.  But feel good answers for labor are not necessarily the right answers for leaders and managers.

You cannot consistently use a planning value, an estimate, that has so much contingency in there to handle any and every threat, every random and non random variable, in order to meet that estimate 100% or near 100% of the time.  Labor will want this and will scream for it but as a manager you cannot allow it.  Fat estimates are not competitive and, if you want to stay in business, you have to commit to far more aggressive estimates and figure out how to get it done.  Get comfortable with P30 and P40 estimates.

Parkinson's and Student Syndrome are real phenomena.  If you do not challenge your estimates, you will end up with a constantly growing and overworked team that is producing nothing more than previously produced.

Teams adapt.  With pressure, teams will adapt and find new ways to be successful.  This is how innovation works.  Without pressure, no change.  This is not management BS.  This is science.

Notwithstanding contractual issues, there is no link between working over 40 hours and low morale and increased errors.  The origin of 40 hours it not based on science but based on politics.  Human capacity can handle way more than this before both morale and errors increase.  Morale is more tied to purpose, autonomy, and mastery.  Nothing about 40 hours.  Again, science, not labor feel good pop psychology.

There is a point of degradation in performance.  You'd be surprised how far out that is than what it feels like.  But without metrics to show when this is occurring, you have nothing.  You cannot establish the judgement of "too aggressive" without metrics to show it...not one or two observations but consistent observations over a period of time of degraded performance.

Flame suit is on....

Comment: I am not the DV, but I don't feel this is a good answer as it boils down to "suck it up". Whilst I would agree with the principles of driving innovation through pressure you are espousing, I got a distinct feeling that is not what the OP is describing. His has all the hallmarks of unrelenting and crushing pressure on a team, which many high-level managers consider to be "sweating the assets". The problem is that working a creative field where, after a point, you cannot be more productive by "working smarter", crushing pressure is exactly that; crushing. The OP is asking for coping strategies

Comment: @MarvMills, the OP supplied no metrics.  We don't know the before level of performance or the after level.  We don't know his pre and post defect density values.  It appears the aggressive deadlines are just now coming in and his team is just now starting to exceed a forty-hour work week.  The only evidence we have is the team is complaining.

Comment: There is no hint of 'just suck it up' in my answer.  I am suggesting to analyze this situation like a leader.

Comment: @DavidEspina to be fair on the team they are not paid to work overtime, so if the work exceeds 40 hours a week it is unethical for the sales team to expect the team to work beyond their contracted hours.

Comment: @DavidEspina what do you use to measure pre and post defect density levels? I use a cumulative flow diagram to measure overall progress btw

Comment: @bobo2000, sure, that's a contractual issue, not a human capacity issue.  Pens down at 40, end of story.  But that's evidence that the team is far away from capacity.  In the US, developers are an exempt role, which means they're salary and work well above 40 hours not "paid."

Comment: Maybe use rate of defect identification or scenario failure over time, like a trend.  Your cumulative flow will show bottlenecks based on capacity; you can show pre and post using that graphic.  You can show an inability to resolve Sev 1 and 2 defects pre and post.  And what about employee turnover?  If morale is dropping, that should increase.

Comment: My final comment::  as a leader, you are obligated to push your team to its sustainable limits, eeking out every piece of value you can for every $ you spend.  You know you're there when your metrics degrade and cannot recover without a material change in your delivery model, i.e., team can no longer adapt.  Pushing people to their limits is not a morale degrader but could actually boost it.  If morale drops, something else is wrong.

Comment: @DavidEspina You may not have intended it to read that way but that is how it read to me because, I guess, instead of commenting on the requested coping strategies you seem to be saying that this pressure is healthy and the team should not be having the problems they are demonstrably having.

Comment: I don't think bobo2000 indicated they are having these problems as he said he "warned..." of problems.  That suggests a prediction, not issue reporting, right?  I am trying to get people to see this problem in a different way.  I think there are other factors to analyze that is NOT labor friendly on the surface.  Clearly I will get dinged for this but I don't think I am wrong.

Comment: Overtime is bad resource management. "Your inability to plan is not my problem". I highly agree that pressure IS good. But constant/frequent overtime requests (to people who do not wish it) is definitely poor resource management, and will end up in an opposite effect.

Comment: @iDevlop, there is no evidence of low morale or degraded performance for a work week over 40 hours.  Forty hours was not introduced as a legal work week based on science but rather politics.  There are a whole host of exempt roles that consistently work well over 40 hours, over 50 in many cases, without any adverse performance sequalae, including morale.